# How to add variable to a value query? Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to obtain a value according to the client that corresponds to a variable.

```
var number=document.getElementById("ideNumber").value;
const con = firebase.database().ref("list/"+sector);
con.on("value",snap=>{var a=snap.val()+number});
```

As a result I get [Object object] 36

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node is named `sector` in your JSON, so it should likely be a hard-coded string in your code too:

```
var number=document.getElementById("ideNumber").value;
const con = firebase.database().ref("list/sector");
con.on("value",snap=>{
  console.log(snap.val());
});
```

Note that any code that needs the value from the database, will need to be inside the callback (where I put the `console.log`) or be called from there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.